# Error: bool undeclared (first use in the function). Have already included <stdbool.h> in the code

Tags: gcc, nvml

I'm trying to compile Perl bindings to Nvidia Management library (NVML). When I use the makefile, following errors appear:

```
/usr/lib/powerpc64le-linux-gnu/perl/5.22/CORE/handy.h:117:34: error: ‘bool’ undeclared (first use in this function)
 #define cBOOL(cbool) ((cbool) ? (bool)1 : (bool)0)

/usr/lib/powerpc64le-linux-gnu/perl/5.22/CORE/handy.h:117:39: error: expected ‘:’ before numeric constant
 #define cBOOL(cbool) ((cbool) ? (bool)1 : (bool)0)
```

gcc version is: gcc (Ubuntu/IBM 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2) 5.4.0 20160609

I've included stdbool.h file in handy.h.

Comment: Do you mean you've edited `handy.h` manually?

Comment: yes. Instead, should I add some flag in makefile?

Comment: What are the preceding 40 or so lines of `handy.h`?

Comment: This file already contains plenty of logic to handle bool, you would need to (revert to the original file and) check what exactly is going on, what does HAS_BOOL expand to? I_STDBOOL? PERL_BOOL_AS_CHAR? etc.

Comment: Yes, from the logic it seems it should handle bool. Has the errors anything to do with gcc version/packages? Also how to check what HAS_BOOL expands to?